# Examples of "irregularities" in mathematics, other than prime numbers

Tags: soft-question, big-list, examples

Prime numbers are the prime example (no pun intended) for something that arises apparently without describable patters; we know that infinitely many exist, that gaps between them can be arbitrarily large, but also that no matter how far you go, you will always eventually find [small gaps](https://www.quantamagazine.org/yitang-zhang-proves-landmark-theorem-in-distribution-of-prime-numbers-20130519/).

What are other examples of objects in mathematics that crop up without any discernible patters, but are totally unconnected to prime numbers?

Comment: The stable homotopy groups of the sphere are always a good example of an important mathematical structure with no evident patters (of course this doesn't mean there aren't deeper structures behind running the show)

Comment: There are plenty of discernible patterns in the primes, of which you even mentioned some, and the prime number theorem provides more. So the current question is ill-posed.

Comment: Possibly ranks of elliptic curves?

Comment: You mean like digits of $\pi$?

Comment: I want to say, "non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta-function," but the part about "totally unconnected to prime numbers" stops me dead in my tracks.

Answer (score 3):

Finite simple groups.$\mbox{}\mbox{}$

(Not totally unrelated to prime numbers but more general...)